# Python installation on macos

Tags: python, macos, installation, python-idle, macos-monterey

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzZqu.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XqXY.png)I have a macos and recently installed python 3.6.3 version but the IDLE doesn't get open and send the message " this application cannot be opened" Why is that? How can I solve it?

I tried to reinstall it a couple of times but did not help. Still receive same message of " this application cannot be opened"

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the error? I have a hunch that there is more information in this popup than you've included here.

Comment: Just added the screenshots!

Comment: If you try to start IDLE from terminal, with "python3.6 -m idlelib", you might get more information.  But seriously, install something newer.  Where did you get 3.6.3 from?  If not python.org, IDLE may not have been included properly.  3.6 is so old it does not get security updates and 3.6.3 is not even then last release of 3.6 with a python.org installer; 3.6.8 is.  Install the most recent 3.10 if possible.

Comment: Thanks Terry. You're right. I installed a newer update, 3.6.10 and it works fine. I may try 3.10 after I finish my course. They go with 3.6 and it is easy for me to have same version.

Answer (score 0):

(Copying the comment suggestion that worked as the answer.)
At least update from 3.6.3, released 2017-10-3, to at least 3.6.8, released 2018-12-24, or one of the later 3.6 releases.  Marzie said that this worked.

I don't know why this worked, but Apple is willing to break 3rd party apps, especially if not written in their custom system language.  Tcl/tk, the base GUI framework for Python's tkinter, need relatively frequent changes to keep up with Apple's graphics and UI changes.  So upgrading Python (and tcl/tk and tkinter and IDLE) are more important on macOS that on Linux and Windows.  I believe maxOS 11 on Apple's CPUs requires 3.10.

Loading more than one version of Python works fine for me.  Each version gets its own icons and terminal command (python3.6 for 3.6).